# Merge Commit Message Lines wrapped by Git

Tags: git, bash, grep, text-processing

When I type commit messages for one of my project, they are usually in this format:

```
My Commit Header

main: Added a new class
doc: Documented the method that was added to main under the name `FooBar.baz()`.
subproject: Did something that requires a really long description.
```

The problem with these is the fact that they are automatically wrapped by Git. When using `git log` to generate a changelog, I usually end up with something like this (using a format that only prints the body):

```
main: Added a new class
doc: Documented the method that was added to main
under the name `FooBar.baz()`.
subproject: Did something that requires a
really long description.
```

What I want to do now is merge these lines so that every line in the output starts with a `tag:` and ends with a period `.`. Unfortunately, the lines can also contain dots, as shown in the second example. So a line ending could probably defined as a period followed by a newline.

I could use the regex `^[\w()]+:.*\n.*\.$`, but I don't know how to apply it to multiple lines using `grep`.

**Is there a way to merge two lines matching a regex using standard Unix / Mac OS commands?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not git that wraps lines in your commit messages. It's the editor that you use to write the commit message. Therefore, to disable wrapping you must properly configure the editor. Note, however, that this may be counter to the generally accepted [etiquette](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#wrap-72) of [writing good commit messages](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/writing-good-commit-messages).

Hence, it may be wiser allowing the editor to wrap the lines, and restore them while viewing the changelog, just as you requested. The following script will do the unwrapping job (unwrapping doesn't cross boundaries defined by empty lines):

**unwrap_commit_message_lines**

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is for the GNU variant of sed!
sed -n -e '/^$\|^[^ :]\+: / {x;p;d}'                               \
       -e '/^[^ :]\+: /! {H;x;s/\(^[^ :]\+: .\+\) *\n */\1 /;x};'  \
       -e '$ {x;p};'                                               \
```

**Usage example:**

```
$ git log --format=format:'------------%ncommit %H%n%n%b'|unwrap_commit_message_lines
```

Comment: > *It's the editor that you use to write the commit message.* Or maybe just the terminal, or pager that `git log` is using?